# Chrome Web Store extension download count

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I made an app as an extension on Chrome Web Store. I would like to know the download count for my extension.

From the developer's dashboard I can access to Statistics, but the graphic starts in 21/5/2015 (three months ago) and the CSV file too.

How can I see the complete download history?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't keep any more than that. What I did was to link it to google analytics and have a custom goal that tracks the install pages as the completion.

Comment: It seems that the only way to get the download count is with a workaround. I think that `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` could be used for a workaround too. Please, feel free to add your method as an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a Google Analytics account using it to track installs is probably a pretty close estimate of downloads.

- Once you create your Analytics account, you create a new property with the default URL being your extension page. For example, `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<extension-name>/<extension-id>`
- Once you get your tracking id, add that to the edit page for your extension in the webstore developer dashboard.
- Once you have done that go to the Analytics admin panel and on the right click *Goals*. Add a new *Custom* goal of *Destination* type for the *RegEx* match of `/track_install/.*`.
- You can now add a graph of this goal completion to track installs.

[Here is a comparison](https://embed.gyazo.com/1817e3a17c9e3c5a8b8c9701a7da1f01.png) of the data collected by Google Analytics and the Statistics in the webstore developer dashboard.

Comment: "...with the default URL being your extension page", could you give an example? Do you refer to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<extension-name>/<extension-id>`?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I use.

Comment: and is the Google Analytics number equal to the Statistics in your developer's dashboard? for one specific day, for example

Comment: @IvanRF It isn't 1-1. My extension doesn't get very much traffic, but it might just have to do when the store collects the data compared to the actual time. The error seems to be +-3 for me, but it might be more pronounced with popular extensions. Here is a [comparison](https://i.gyazo.com/1817e3a17c9e3c5a8b8c9701a7da1f01.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I've just configured Google Analytics and I saw the `/track_install/` page on the real-time section :)

Comment: the difference can be large compared to store stats because it also tracks uninstalls while analytics do not. people just trying an extension will later uninstall.

Comment: one of my extensions for example is currently one of the 5 featured ones in the large top marquee in the store extensions front. this is great but causes many random people to just try it without really needing it.

Comment: @ZigMandel do you track downloads with another method?

Comment: no i dont. i rely on store stats to know total users, and track installs with analytics like this answer. you could track it more precisely with a server and the extension  can ping it say once a day at most

Comment: worth noting that the above still works. However in the chrome developer dashboard where it asks for the analytics ID you have to remove the 'UA-' prefix from it. The old dashboard had the UA- written before the input so it was obvious, the current one doesnt so you have to guess.